# initializing a **Array and what actually need to be in the title so it goes through

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

A function I want to use requires an input of a `float **` array.

How can i initialize this to be a 2x2 array?

Just using `float[2][2] = {{0,100},{0,200}}` obviously doesn´t work.

I also tried

```
float** ranges = new float*[2];
ranges[0] = {0,100};
ranges[1] = {0,200};
```

Comment: `float **` is not an array, but a pointer to pointer.

Comment: `float[2][2] = {{0,100},{0,200}} `  --> `float ranges[2][2] = {{0.0,100.0},{0.0,200.0}}; `

Comment: the title is befor the and. I need to get the values int here and dont lnow how basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float** ranges = new float*[2];
ranges[0] = {0,100};
ranges[1] = {0,200};
```

doesn't work since:

1. The RHS is an initilaization list that cannot be assigned to a pointer.
2. `range[0]` and `range[1]` are pointers for which memory needs to be allocated first. And then, you can assign values to individual elements.

You can use:

```
ranges[0] = new float[2]{0,100};
ranges[1] = new float[2]{0,200};
```

or

```
ranges[0] = new float[2];
ranges[0][0] = 0;
ranges[0][1] = 100;
ranges[1] = new float[2];
ranges[1][0] = 0;
ranges[1][1] = 200;
```

Of course, make sure to add code to `delete` them.